# Proof by induction of number of solutions to $m$-tuples with non-negative integers that add to a non-negative integer $n$

Tags: induction

I have the following problem

> Prove by induction that there are $S(m,n) = \binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$ solutions to:
> $$\sum_{i=1}^m x_i = n$$ where $m \geq 1$, each $x_i$ is a non-negative integer as is $n$.

Clearly, the base case $S(1,0)$ is the number of solutions to $x_i = 0$ which is $1$, and the formula verifies this. I started by inducting on $m$, and considered $\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} x_i = n$. If $x_{m+1} = 0$, there are clearly $S(m,n)$ solutions. This is where I don't know how to proceed, what is the argument if $x_{m+1}>0$?

I am familiar with the usual stars-and-bars method, but I would like to prove it this way instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proof by induction, the number of ways of grouping unlabelled objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436055/proof-by-induction-the-number-of-ways-of-grouping-unlabelled-objects) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5Em%20x_i%3Dn%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24S(m%2Cn)%3D%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bm-1%7D%7Bm-1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainduction%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). Note this [answer](/a/1436179) there states ...

Comment: (cont.) "The problem is equivalent to finding the number of solutions of equation $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_m = n$ where $a_i >= 0$ for all i." Also, a closely related post is [Cardinality of partitions of a number](/q/3180323).